# Responsive Credits area at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I have created the following div:

```html
<div class="author">Photography by Carla Bertomeu Photography </div>
```

The CSS for my div is:

```css
.author {
position: fixed;
top: 47vw;
left: 50vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-size: 0.8vw;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
color: white;
}
```

This works perfect. When I resize my screen, the Div text won't go out of place.

Hower when I try to do the same with a image, the image gets out of place when I resize the window because the size stays the same. Here is the setup:

HTML:

```html
<div id="facebook">
<img class="facebook-bottom" src="facebook-colored.png" alt="Facebook" />
<img class="facebook-top" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#facebook {
max-width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 48vw;
left: 50vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#facebook img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#facebook img.facebook-top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

What would be the best way to make the image smaller, just like the text when I resize the window?

Comment: Have you tried to give to you images `max-width: 100%` in order to restrict them into parent's dimensions?

Comment: Specify either width or height for the image in a relative unit as well, and the other one as auto ...

Comment: @CBroe Could you show me how this is done?

Comment: Could you explain what about it is unclear?

Comment: @CBroe I do not know if I have to specify it in the HTML or CSS, I am very new to this, I would appreciate a code example in my code

Comment: `#facebook img { width: 10vw; height: auto; }`

Comment: @CBroe This worked, thank you! the only downside is that when I hover over the image, the transition is not that smooth but I will try to find a way around that, maybe you know a way to fix this already?